# I have an error with the build of my nextjs project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

[image][image: I want to upload my project to Vercel but i have a problem with the build, i am new in this, so i don't know what to do, please help me]

I want to upload my project to Vercel but i have a problem with the build, i am new in this, so i don't know what to do, please help me, the first pic is the error that i have in Vercel

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: i dont know, the error that i have in vercel is this: > Build error occurred
11:01:43.303   Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
11:01:43.303    /
11:01:43.303    /404
11:01:43.303    /Store
11:01:43.303       at exportApp (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:30:1103)
11:01:43.303       at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
11:01:43.303       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
11:01:43.303       at async build (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:39:69)

Comment: i add the pic for you can see it better

Comment: Try `next build` instead of `next export` for your build command.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same error. My solution was to delete one file (it wasn't currently in use). It was impeding the page from being built and, then, deployed. Check your '/', '/404' and '/Store' files. Try to look for any importations you may be missing, and also look for errors with any of your routes, if you're using them, those can be quite tricky.

Also, feel free to share the code in those 3 files aforementioned.